# Python spacing between outputted text in the shell

Tags: python, shell

I have recently been trying out python and what it can be used for. So I need help with some code thats being outputted to the shell.

The code currently looks like this:

```
"print ("Hello and welcome to my world")
"print ("I'd like you to meet my family")
```

This is outputted into the shell as:

```
Hello and welcome to my world
I'd like you to meet my family
```

Is there any command I can put a space in-between the two outputted lines so that it looks like this?:

```
Hello and welcome to my world

I'd like you to meet my family
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, add an empty print statement between the two other print statements

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 2,

```
print ("Hello and welcome to my world")
print
print ("I'd like you to meet my family")
```

Or if you use Python 3,

```
print ("Hello and welcome to my world")
print ()
print ("I'd like you to meet my family")
```

Or use `\n`. This works with any version of Python.

```
print ("Hello and welcome to my world\n")
print ("I'd like you to meet my family")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra line feed to the first line:

```
print ("Hello and welcome to my world\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `\n` whenever you wanna skip the line